# How to account for jumps in intraday data when calculating beta?

Tags: equities, high-frequency, modeling, market-data, beta

I am calculating betas on intraday trade data at 15-minute intervals. For simplicity sake, let's assume I am modeling

\begin{equation}
Y = \beta * X + c
\end{equation}

where $Y$ is the return of XLF and $X$ is the return of SPY.

If I want to run this on five days of intraday data, should I remove the jump that happens due to opening gaps on the next day?

How do you guys usually handle this jump in returns ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using *returns* to compute beta, not the *prices*. And yes, remove the "jumps", though this should happen automatically since you're looking only at intraday returns. One final piece of advice: you'll get more meaningful results if you smooth the returns via a moving average.

Comment: Did you mean smooth the price via moving average ? If not, not really sure how taking a moving average of returns would give more meaningful results. Can you explain

Comment: Smooth the returns because that will decrease momentary variation.

Comment: @chrisaycock What moving average window would you suggest? At 15 minutes per period, there is only 26 periods/day.

Comment: @RobertKubrick A five-period average should work well.

Comment: @silencer Are you calculating beta to fit a model or to hedge a portfolio? In the first cast I would tend to smooth data less. Also, are you holding positions overnight?

Comment: Fitting a model. And no I dont hold positions overnight,

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above I can suggest:

- ignore data point if returns are more than a certain threshold (2 s.d.)
- calculate at different sampling intervals and choose most stable beta with the best significance (certain longer intervals "smooth out" small to mid size jumps)

Comment: This answer is much better than your previous answers. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the regression separately for 5 days, and average the betas you get for different days.